# Iterate through a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying append a 'gameID' to a list if the game has been finished. I have a list of dictionaries called 'games_2020' that looks like

(ex.    [ {'seasonYear': '2020', 'league': 'standard', 'gameID': '8133', 'statusGame': 'Finished', 'vTeam': LA}, {'seasonYear': '2020', 'league': 'standard', 'gameID': '8134', 'statusGame': 'Finished', 'vTeam': LA}.....]

My current code is below. 'gameID_finished' is where I want the 'gameID' for finished games to end up. games_2020 is what I want to iterate through. I am then trying to map through the entire list but I am running into an output of all the same 'gameID'

```
def check_finish(games):

    if games_2020['statusGame'] == 'Finished':
       gameID_finished.append(games_2020['gameID'])
    else:
       print('Scheduled')
```

Comment: Please create a [mre] that we can execute and see your problem. this code does not contain any looping or hardcoded data. If I add a call to `check_finish(..)` I do not know what `games` is - and it it throws `NameException` on `games_2020` and  `gameID_finished`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse each item in list to append to output. Please try the below code.

```
gameID_finished = []
games = [ {'seasonYear': '2020', 'league': 'standard', 'gameID': '8133', 'statusGame': 'Finished', 'vTeam': 'LA'}, {'seasonYear': '2020', 'league': 'standard', 'gameID': '8134', 'statusGame': 'Finished', 'vTeam': 'LA'}]

for games_2020 in games:
    if games_2020['statusGame'] == 'Finished':
       gameID_finished.append(games_2020['gameID'])
    else:
       print('Scheduled')
```